# ActivityIndicator not spinning or animated only static image on Android

Tags: android, react-native, activity-indicator

Activity Indicator in react native working fine on IOS but its not spinning or animating on android, any help ???

```
<View style{{marginLeft:0,width:60,height:60,borderRadius: 30,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center", backgroundColor:'#eee', borderColor:"#fff", borderWidth:1 }}>
    <ActivityIndicator size="small" animating={true}/>
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: tried adding flex: 1 to your view?

Comment: I added flex:1, but still the same !!!

Comment: its visible but not spinning, I added a image to this question too,

Comment: After sending a edit suggestion I saw an image linked! My bad

Answer (score 12):

I faced this issue too and the cause is that I had the animations disabled (scaled to x0) in developer options. If you change this configuration (animation scale) or disable developer options it should fix your issue. Hope it helps

Comment: This comment was extremely helpful.  I tried a bunch of different solutions.  None of them worked until I turned on animations in the developer options!

Comment: Lol, now that you mentioned it... I have the same settings.

Comment: The question is, who did it? The answer is Google. They never fail to disappoint us, do they? :D

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<View
    style={[
       StyleSheet.absoluteFill, {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          zIndex: 99,
       },
    ]}>
    <ActivityIndicator color="#fff" />
 </View>
```

Still facing any issue?? check the live demo

https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/activityindicator-demo

Comment: check the live demo you need to import some packages

Comment: And @WathsalaDeSilva try running my live demo on you hardware device, If that works than you are doing some mistake in you script.

Comment: `import { View, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';` you need to add the `StyleSheet`

Comment: I already added those packages but not animating the indicator on android

Comment: This means you are going wrong somewhere else my solution should fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the animations if they are turned off on your emulator or real device.

On Android devices (including emulators), you can enable them as follows:

1. Go to the **Settings**
2. Scroll down and tap on **About phone** or **About device**
3. Tap **Build number** multiple times (usually at least five) until it says *Developer mode enabled*
4. Go back to **Settings**, where you should now see **Developer options**, tap it
5. Scroll down to the **Drawing** section
6. There, tap each of the following:

- **Window animation scale**
- **Transition animation scale**
- **Animator duration scale**

and set animations to a desired speed. By default, these options are set to 1x, which means that animations will be played at their normal speed. If for any reason you need speeds slower or faster, choose one of the values smaller or greater than 1x.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with steps:

Go to the Developer options in the settings

**Steps:**

> 1- Settings
>
> 2- System
>
> 3- Developer Options [if not available search on how to activate
> developer options/developer mode in your Android phone]

4- In the Developer Options page, Search for(Scroll to)
**Drawing Section**

5- Activate

- Window Animation Scale.
- Transition Animation Scale.
- Animator Duration Scale.

[For me I choose Animation scale 0.5x in the three options]

Now, go back to the expo app and reload.

Answer (score -1):

I implemented the same code in my react native project...worked for me

```
<View style={{ marginLeft:0, width:60,height:60,borderRadius: 30,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center", backgroundColor:'#eee', borderColor:"#fff", borderWidth:1 }}>
    <ActivityIndicator size="small" animating />
  </View>
```

By the way you forgot `=` sign after style (First line),
my guess is this problem is not due to this view, maybe some parent component.

Comment: in my code it has  "=" mark , I messed up copying that code, my bad!!! I added "=" mark and that is not the issue,